# After an upgrade, Chromium doesn’t see any of my extensions anymore

Tags: debian, chrome

I’m using Debian in its testing (9th) version.

I did a package upgrade two days ago, and since then Chromium doesn’t have any extensions installed. Flash isn’t working either (but it wasn’t working already before the upgrade).

`chromium:amd64` was in version 55.0.2883.75-3 and now is in version 55.0.2883.75-6.

My `~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/` folder still has all of its extensions in there, but chromium doesn’t seem to want to use them.

If I try to install a new extension, I get the error, “installation is not enabled” but I can’t find any option that will let me enable extensions installation.

How do I get my extensions working again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-packaged extensions have been [disabled](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-chromium/pkg-chromium.git/tree/debian/NEWS) for security reasons, since version 55.0.2883.75-4 of the package. To re-enable them, you need to run Chromium with the `--enable-remote-extensions` option; if you want to do so permanently, you should copy `/usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications` and add the option to the `Exec` line:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium --enable-remote-extensions %U
```

Note that updating extensions has been (mistakenly) disabled; it's worth tracking [#841401](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=841401) for updates on that issue.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on 70.0.3538.35. The message about not allowed installation from web site appears even after enabling switch as you suggested: /usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chrome --extra-plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/nsbrowser/plugins --enable-remote-extensions

Comment: @kensai extensions have seen [quite a few changes in 70](https://blog.chromium.org/2018/10/trustworthy-chrome-extensions-by-default.html), you might need to adjust your preferences in the browser too (I haven’t checked yet).

Comment: Actually by drag&drop cr extension directly it didn't work, but by loading as unpacked it worked.